# Which site deals with career development questions for programmers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any site in the network where career development questions about the programming profession can be asked ? I thought Programmer's was the site for it, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Hmmm, the [possible dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98683/179419) I could find is _waaay_ out of date and suggests Programmers as the best choce (it's explicitly off-topic there)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I have seen the old questions. All of them are from 2011.

Answer (score 2):

There is no site specifically geared to *programming* careers, but there is the [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site, where you questions may be on-topic. (Check their FAQ before asking.)

Comment: [Workplace.SE] is not for career development.

Comment: @AshRj hm 100+ questions in [Workplace career-development tag](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) speak rather against your statement

Comment: @gnat Look at the questions as well. They are all generic questions. Some of the more specific technical questions are closed as off-topic.

Comment: @AshRj could you please elaborate on that? I am having difficulty finding an example of what you mentioned, "more specific technical questions" that are closed there

Comment: Certainly there are many "career development" type questions that are specific to one person and should be closed as Too Localized anywhere; the Workplace FAQ does point out a few of these (like "which job should I take?" type questions), but I can certainly imagine more general ones that would count as "career development" and fit in there.